# ffmpeg : generate different multibitrate video from single input

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to generate multiple multibitrate files from one single resource.

I want to generate 4 different quality file : 240p , 360p , 720p , 1080p.

My requirement is suppose i provide a file having 360p quality then only 2 file get generated 
1) 240p
2) 360p

If, I provide a file having 720p quality then 3 files get generated
1) 240p
2) 360p
3) 720p

Exactly same like youtube. (If you upload higher quality video then it provides more quality option , if you upload lower quality video then it provide less quality option).

Is there any ffmpeg command which do same? i.e from single input source it identify and generate multibitrate file of lower bitrate automatically.